# ASP.Net Dropzone inside normal form to upload files to MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, dropzone.js

I've looked and looked for a good response to this situation but can't seem to find any at the moment. I'm wanting to let my users upload files into the dropzone and then why they hit submit let the MVC action do something with those files (More specifically this action will be sending an email to the contact with the attachments but thats for later).

The problem is every tutorial or fix I've seen has me setting my whole form up as the dropzone and I don't want to do that. I currently have it working so that when a user drags a file to the dropzone it calls a server side script and saves the file in a temp folder, but ideally I would like to just have the file available in the stream when I enter my MVC action.

*I want the form to look like this in the end, not have the whole form wrapped as a dropzone -*

[image: Dropzone Example]

**Form Wrapper / Form Jquery:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Partners", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "smart-form client-form", id = "contact-form", enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.Partial("_ContactForm")

}

@section pagespecific {

    <!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S) -->
    <script src="/scripts/plugin/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
                // This is the url I don't want it to go to, I want to go to the MVC Action
                url: "../App_Service/hn_FileUpload.ashx",
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                maxFilesize: 0.5,
                dictDefaultMessage: '<span class="text-center"><span class="font-lg visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-lg-block"><span class="font-lg"><i class="fa fa-caret-right text-danger"></i> Drop files <span class="font-xs">to upload</span></span><span>&nbsp&nbsp<h4 class="display-inline"> (Or Click)</h4></span>',
                dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!',
                success: function (file, response) {
                    var imgName = response;
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
                },
                error: function (file, response) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

**Form Content:**

```
<header>
    Contact Form
</header>

<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col col-6">
            @Html.Label("Contact Name", new { @class = "label" })
            <label class="input">
                @Html.TextBox("ContactName", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col col-6">
            @Html.Label("Email Address", new { @class = "label" })
            <label class="input">
                @Html.TextBox("ContactEmail", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </label>
        </section>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <section>
        @Html.Label("Attachment:", new { @class = "label" })
        <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">

        </div>
    </section>
</fieldset>

<footer>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
    </button>
</footer>
```

Dropzone Jquery:

Comment: Sorry for being late  , How did you solve it?

Comment: I unfortunately never did. We had to drop this altogether.